# customPages url not working for parse server password reset

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I have my Parse server set up on Heroku and I'm using the emailAdapter for Mailgun integration. I have the emails sending properly, but the link is not working correctly. From what I understand,  the user should be directed to the link defined in customPages. Instead, the user is directed to: 
https://url.com/parse/apps/my-parse-app-id/request_password_reset?token=WVu39ZyNsPWOA7dbF4h6386bE&username=emailaddress%40yahoo.com.

Please see below for reference

```
publicServerURL: 'https://url.com/parse',

appName: 'My App',

emailAdapter: {

  module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',

  options: {

    fromAddress: 'noreply@url.com',
    domain: 'mg.url.com',
    apiKey: 'key-mykey',

    }
  },

customPages: {

invalidLink: 'http://url.com/link_invalid',
verifyEmailSuccess: 'http://url.com/verify_email_success',
choosePassword: 'https://url.com/choose_password',
passwordResetSuccess: 'http://url.com/sucess'

}
```

Comment: check the "public server url" in your config in the index.js where you run parse-server

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation  [here](https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/custom-parse-options) I had an issue when I was trying to set the custom pages, I tried this and it worked for me

```js
{
   "customPages": {
      "invalidLink":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/invalid_link.html",
      "verifyEmailSuccess":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/verify_email_success.html",
      "choosePassword":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/choose_password.html", 
      "passwordResetSuccess":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/password_reset_success.html",
      "invalidVerificationLink":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/invalid_verification_link.html",
      "linkSendFail":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/link_send_fail.html",
      "linkSendSuccess":"https://<subdomain>.b4a.app/link_send_success.html"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The user will be sent to your "*publicServerURL/parse/apps/..."* and then redirected to the "*choosePassword*" url.

One thing I don't understand is that your choosePassword seem to be hosted on the same domain as your parse server, unless you used the same example domain.  I would expect something like:

```
publicServerURL: 'https://serverurl.com/parse',
...
customPages: {

invalidLink: 'http://url.com/link_invalid',
verifyEmailSuccess: 'http://url.com/verify_email_success',
choosePassword: 'https://url.com/choose_password',
passwordResetSuccess: 'http://url.com/sucess'

}
```

Another thing you might want to check is http vs https in your customPages.